# Is the chipset defined as a bus?

Tags: motherboard, chipset

So the chipset is the northbridge and southbridge, and connects all the hardware-components to the CPU. And the bus's are the mediums connecting said bridges together, connecting the northbridge to the CPU, and connecting the hardware-components to the bridges.

To me, it seems they do the same thing: connect hardware-components. Is the chipset defined as a bus? If not, why not? How do the mechanics of these two things differ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bus is a physical, electrical connection that connects devices that already have the capability to speak the same electrical protocol. The chipset is a logical connection, providing the capability of connecting devices that speak different electrical protocols.

For example, if I talk to you, at the top of the protocol stack we have English. English can be communicated in writing, it can be thought, it can be spoken. But in this case, below that we have spoken words. Now those spoken words could pass over electrical wires, they can pass through the air. But in this case, we have vibrations in air at the bottom of the stack.

Similarly, when devices communicate, we also have a stack. At the bottom of the stack, we have the physical, electrical connection with functions like "this string of bits". That's the bus. Above that, we have the implementation of the protocol used over that connection with functions like "store this chunk of data in this place". That's what the chipset does. And above that, we typically have a higher-level, functional protocol with functions like "send this packet of data to this address", that's what the device itself does.

For example, the chipset has to figure out which commands go to which devices. A bus itself cannot do that.